# Is there sort of unzip modules in nginx?

Tags: linux, module, nginx

I'm writing a filter module of nginx, as a proxy, i want 2 change few specific content

First , i need to **decompress the gzip page**.

Before a write a own ugly one, i want to know is there already a module can do this, cause i think this is a basic needs..

#include

Comment: I simply don't know whether or not **no one else has needed it**...

Answer (score 2):

There is the gunzip module in nginx:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gunzip_module.html