# does nginx support compress the request to the upstream?

Tags: nginx

Dose nginx supprt this ?
Whoul you please show me some configuration of it?

```
[Client]           [Nginx Reverse Proxy]               [BackEnd]
   |   [Raw Post]         |    [gzip encoded request]     |   
   |--------------------> | ----------------------------->|
   |                      |                               |  
   |   [Raw Response]     |    [gzip encoded response]    |
   | <------------------  | <-----------------------------|
   |                      |                               |
```

Comment: why wouldn't it? if you configure nginx as a proxy it will act as a proxy

Comment: My requirement is using nginx to do the compression / decompression, to reduce the network traffic without modify the client. Would you please give an example of nginx config?

Comment: gzip compression is a widely recognized compresion method for HTTP requests and kinda all browsers or other kind of software that uses HTTP requests support it, why do you want to send the data raw?

Comment: Sorry, the "Client" is not support gzip encoding/decoding that is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there is some way to do this. Nginx has a `gunzip` module that gzip decompresses responses:

> The ngx_http_gunzip_module module is a filter that decompresses
>   responses with “Content-Encoding: gzip” for clients that do not
>   support “gzip” encoding method. The module will be useful when it is
>   desirable to store data compressed, to save space and reduce I/O
>   costs.
>
> This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the
>   --with-http_gunzip_module configuration parameter.

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gunzip_module.html

Then you can use it like:

```
gunzip on;
```

Hope that works for you.

Also see this SO question:
[Is there sort of unzip modules in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521551/is-there-sort-of-unzip-modules-in-nginx)

Answer (score 2):

The full and correct answer is that nginx *can* do this, but with a couple of caveats. In order to provide an uncompressed response to the edge client (user PC), you must compile nginx with the `gunzip` module - which isn't built/included by default. This is the opposite of the gzip module, and allows nginx to unzip already-compressed resources found on disk or obtained from a backend server.

So when compiling nginx, include this:
`--with-http_gunzip_module`

And in your `nginx.conf`, you'll have a block like this to describe requests to be obtained from a backend server:

```
    location @backend {
        ...
        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.xxx;
        gunzip on;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "gzip";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off gzip compression in nginx by setting the `gzip` directive to `off` in your `nginx.conf`:

```
gzip off
```

Additionally you can turn of gzip compression for proxied requests only:

```
gzip_proxied off
```

Nginx has a great wiki where all this information is clearly explained:
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule

About nginx proxying: also clearly described in the nginx wiki:

> Example:
>
> ```
> location / {
>   proxy_pass        http://localhost:8000;
>   proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
> }
> ```

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule

There are many different ways to set up a proxy so you should dive in and see what you need exactly, there's no 'one' answer to this.

Comment: Errr.... Maybe my question is not cleaner.
My problem is, the client doesn't support gzip, I need proxy to do the gzip encoding / gzip decoding for the client.

Comment: Why doesn't your backend just send back raw data? You want nginx to decode it and then send it through? That's kind of a super-weird process, I don't think it is possible as nginx wasn't invented to do that.